# What does it mean to cast spells from a magic item "using your spell save DC"?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, difficulty-class

This is taken from the description of the [Staff of the Woodlands](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-woodlands) (emphasis added by me):

> You can use an action to expend 1 or more of the staff's charges to cast one of the following spells from it, **using your spell save DC**

What does "using your spell save DC" mean?

Comment: Hi FoXpoX, and welcome to the site. You've accepted my answer pretty quickly, so I feel like I should make sure you know: if another answer comes along that you feel explains things better or is more useful *to you*, you have the ability to un-accept mine and accept another. In any case, enjoy the staff and happy gaming!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the DMG at ["Activating an Item"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/treasure#ActivatinganItem) (p. 141):

> A magic item, *such as certain staffs*, may require you to use your own spellcasting ability when you cast a spell from the item. If you have more than one spellcasting ability you choose which one to use with the item. If you don't have a spellcasting ability... your spellcasting ability modifier is +0, and your proficiency bonus does apply.

(Emphasis mine.)

Thus you calculate your DC as normal: **8 + proficiency bonus + spellcasting ability modifier**.

If you don't have a spellcasting ability - and thus have no spellcasting ability modifier - then your spell save DC is just **8 + proficiency bonus + 0**. (For the Staff of the Woodlands, which requires attunement by a druid, this is likely only possible for 13th-level [Thief rogues](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#Thief), who have the Use Magic Device feature and can thus ignore class requirements on the use of the staff.)

Comment: Since the item in question is Staff of the Woodlands, I think we can assume that the character is a Druid and that the spell save DC is 8 + prof. + WIS.

Comment: I've just glanced at the DMG (since other questions claimed proficiency bonus does apply), and indeed it says "your proficiency bonus *does* apply" (emphasis mine). So I think in fact the DC for non-spellcasters should be 8 + proficiency bonus.

Comment: @vigil good catch. I'm afk and afb for the weekend-any chance you can edit it in?

Comment: @nitsua60 sure, done :)